# Filling similar jaxb generated classes

Tags: java, jaxb, software-design

The project I'm currently working on has 2 xml documents that need te be created. not that it matters, but to make these are:
 - direct debits(pain 008) 
 - credit transfer(pain 001).

The xsd's for these messages have lots of similarities. I'm using jaxb to generate classes, then I fill the generated classes with content and then generate the xml.
I have finished coding the content for the first xml which took quite some lines of code.

Now I'm starting with the credit transfer message. I'd like to reuse as much as possible code written for the direct debits, but the credit transfer has a different ObjectFactory, and thus different classes(same classes but in different package/namespace)

Of course I have extracted all code to generate the content, but this still leaves me with a lot of setters

Is there a better way to generate the xml documents?

edit-
Question is on hold therefore some code:
There are 2 xml messages I need to generate. Each has its own xsd.
Each xsd contains a partyidentification32 element. the methods below generate the content:

```
private sepa.pain00100103.PartyIdentification32 createInitiatingParty()   {  
     sepa.pain00100103.PartyIdentification32 partyId = objectFactory.createPartyIdentification32();  
     partyId.setNm("Name");  
     partyId.setAdrs("Streetname");  
     return partyId;  
}

private sepa.pain00100802.PartyIdentification32 createInitiatingParty()   {  
     sepa.pain00100802.PartyIdentification32 partyId = objectFactory.createPartyIdentification32();  
     partyId.setNm("Name");  
     partyId.setAdrs("Streetname");  
     return partyId;  
}
```

As you can see code is almost the same, except the return type.
There are 2 classes of PartyIdentification32 in different packages therefore I have to write the exact same code twice. Jaxb generates these classes so I do not have much control how these are generated.
this is a simple example, but there much more code duplication like this.

My question is, is there a way to solve this in a more elegant way without the code duplication?

Hope this makes the question more clear.